# How to solve the error ''WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'"

Tags: django, hosting, webmin, virtualmin

I am trying to host a django website using virtualmin.Virtualmin script installer support django version 1.7.And i install django 2.2.6 via putty.But i can't access my website.When i access mydomain/admin it shows  " 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user' "  error.How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reboot the machine?
Tried to access through IP or also through a domain by putting: 1000 at the end

tried to check the log error, if so put the log here ...
You can check the log via SSH.

Are you accessing the site via http: //url.tld/ or http: //url.tld/mysite.fcgi/?
Does the mysite.fcgi file belong to the virtual host user?
Did you enable PHP over fcgid?

there is this reference home help please inform how was your process

['WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576192/wsgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-user?rq=1)